# Converting PHP curl_setopt() to Python Requests and to CLI curl

Tags: php, python, curl, python-requests, pycurl

I am trying to convert the following **PHP curl_setopt()** to the equivalent within **Python [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/)** as well as for **CLI curl**. For Python, if not possible in [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/), I will resort using **[pycurl](http://pycurl.io/)**.

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Here is the working **PHP curl** code:

```
$params = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password
);

$params_string = json_encode($params);

$process = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params_string);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec ($process);

curl_close ($process);
```

I am at a loss what I need to set within **Python Requests** for those two **PHP curl_setopt(s)**.

And I have tried the following in **CLI curl**, but I got a **Bad Request** error:

```
AUTHENTICATE_DATA="usename=${USERNAME}&password=${PASSWORD}"

AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE=$(curl \
  -X POST \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-urlencode "${AUTHENTICATE_DATA}" \
  -v \
  ${AUTHENTICATE_URL})

echo ${AUTHENTICATE_RESPONSE}
```

What do I need?

Thank you, appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

This option simply says that the result of `curl_exec()` is passed to a return variable. On the command line, the default is to output to standard output.

```
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

This is a very bad idea and is going to make you vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. There's no excuse to use it. `--insecure` is the equivalent command line option.

Also worth mentioning that you're passing a JSON string as parameter for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, and there's no JSON encoding going on with the CLI code you've got.

Answer (score 4):

Using requests:

```
import requests

url = 'https://...'
username = 'username'
password = 'supersecret'

# curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
# PHP bashing time: Who in their right minds would create a function
# that spews its return value to stdout by default, unless explicitly
# instructed not to do so.
resp = requests.post(

    # $process = curl_init($url);
    url,

    # $params = array(
    #    'username' => $username,
    #    'password' => $password
    # );
    # $params_string = json_encode($params);
    # curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params_string);
    # $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    # curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    json=dict(username=username, password=password),

    # curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    # note: you shouldn't do this, really
    verify=False,

)

data = resp.text
# or if you expect json response
data = resp.json()
```

Comment: Thx, this works great, and changed as suggested to `verify=True`.

Comment: You can skip passing it altogether then, it's `True` by default. You can also use it to pass a ["path to a CA_BUNDLE file or directory with certificates of trusted CAs"](http://www.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/).

Comment: The PHP functions are one-to-one mappings of the cURL API functions, which is why they may not act entirely reasonably! There are better, more modern, ways to handle HTTP requests in PHP.

Comment: from @miken32 _There are better, more modern, ways to handle HTTP requests in PHP._ What are these more modern ways?

Comment: @JeffTanner [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) or an [HTTP client](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/)